# Liferay - how to disable monitoringfilter

Tags: liferay

As the title says.
I tried adding `com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.monitoring.MonitoringFilter=false` to my `portal.properties` but it still seems to be enabled. (getting a response already commited exception on it).
And since it only occurs at the customer and we're not monitoring the performance it seems best to turn it off.

Any input is appreciated.

(liferay-6.0.5)

Answer (score 0):

Be extra extra sure that the portal-ext.properties you mention (you didn't refer to portal.properties, right) is really picked up - there will be a log entry at startup stating which portal-ext.properties is being read.

Put your portal-ext.properties in LIFERAY_HOME, that's the same folder that also has the tomcat, data and deploy folders (if you're on the tomcat bundle).

Also, on Windows, make sure that Windows shows also the extensions. I can't count how many times people created portal-ext.properties.txt and wondered why it wasn't picked up. (this file is only renameable on the command line, not in Explorer, if you have the "hide extension of known files" on.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue as you and can confirm that the IllegalStateException will still occur even the monitoringFilter is disabled. The exception seems to occur on the filterChain, not actually on the MonitoringFilter. See http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-13853